# Calculate Business Hours

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

I am using following code to calculate the buiness hours

```
TimeRange timeRange = new TimeRange(
new DateTime(2018, 1, 08, 10, 00, 00), 
new DateTime(2018, 1, 15, 15, 30, 00));

CalendarDateDiff dateDiff = new CalendarDateDiff();
dateDiff.WorkingHours.Add(new HourRange(9, 18));
dateDiff.AddWorkingWeekDays();

var calendarDateAdd = new CalendarDateAdd();
calendarDateAdd.ExcludePeriods.Add(new Day(2018, 1, 10,calendarDateAdd.Calendar));

TimeSpan nonBusinessHours = dateDiff.Difference(timeRange.Start, timeRange.End);
double businessHours = timeRange.Duration.TotalHours -nonBusinessHours.TotalHours;
return businessHours;
```

The details explanation is in the code project.[Calculate-Business-Hours @ codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/173154/Calculate-Business-Hours). In that code it specify a code to add holidays . But it not correctly working as specified.
The required Nuget package is listed here
[TimePeriodLibrary.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimePeriodLibrary.NET/)

Comment: I would discourage you from using custom date time libraries that have not been heavily vetted. NodaTime is a good library if you are going to step away from the APIs that are built into .NET and has been heavily vetted. Such facilities are very complex and hard to get right. Also, note that readability suffers dramatically due to the lack of overloaded operators.

Comment: What do you mean "it not correctly working as specified"? What is your sample data for the input, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: In the example it mentioned that we can add holidays as 
var calendarDateAdd = new CalendarDateAdd();
calendarDateAdd.ExcludePeriods.Add(new Day(2018, 1, 10,calendarDateAdd.Calendar)); but it does not specify how to use it